# MySql - Update the status of rows using FIFO logic

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've the below mysql table where I want to update multiple rows of `approval_status` field with `1` if the quantity passed is more than the `qty_req` value using MySql or PHP.

Requisition table:

| id | part_id | qty_req | approval_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 20 | 0 |
| 2 | 17 | 30 | 0 |
| 3 | 16 | 40 | 0 |
| 4 | 17 | 50 | 0 |
| 5 | 17 | 60 | 0 |

Example:

```
$update_status=Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [part_id] => 17 [qty] => 90 )
    [1] => Array ( [part_id] => 16 [qty] => 70 ) 
)
```

From the above array, `90` is the quantity available for the `part_id` `17`. I want to update the `approval_status`  as `1` in the `requisition` table for the rows with the `part_id` as 17 with the below scenario:

1. Update the `approval_status`  to `1` as the quantity of the first row with `part_id`  17 is 30 which is less than 90.
2. Update the `approval_status`  to `1` as the quantity of the second row with `part_id`  17 is `30+50=80` which is less than 90.
3. Third row won't update as the total `30+50+60=140`  is greater than 90.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any tutorial to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no anything in your table which sets definite rows order. So the terms "first row", "next row" and so on - not exists. Visual positional ordering is a fake. The task is unsolvable now.

Comment: In order to do what you wish, you must have a reliable column for sorting - something like a date of creation or whatever would be meaningful in the context of your business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single data:

```sql
UPDATE test t1
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT *, SUM(qty_req) OVER (ORDER BY reg_date) cum_sum
               FROM test
               WHERE part_id = @part_id ) t2
SET t1.approval_status = 1 
WHERE cum_sum <= @qty;
```

Multiple data:

```
UPDATE test t1
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT test.*, 
                      SUM(qty_req) OVER (PARTITION BY part_id ORDER BY reg_date) cum_sum,
                      qty
               FROM test
               JOIN JSON_TABLE(@json,
                               '$[*]' COLUMNS ( part_id INT PATH '$.part_id',
                                                qty INT PATH '$.qty')) jsontable USING (part_id) ) t2
SET t1.approval_status = 1 
WHERE cum_sum <= qty;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7cf062d81a138657dee78f3026623783

Column `reg_date` and unique index added for to provide definite and unambiguous rows ordering.

---

The solution applicable to MySQL 5.6:

```sql
UPDATE test t1
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT t1.part_id,
                      t1.qty_req,
                      t1.approval_status,
                      t1.reg_date,
                      SUM(t2.qty_req) cum_sum
               FROM test t1
               JOIN test t2 USING (part_id)
               WHERE t1.reg_date >= t2.reg_date
               GROUP BY t1.part_id,
                        t1.qty_req,
                        t1.approval_status,
                        t1.reg_date ) t2
JOIN ( SELECT 17 part_id, 90 qty
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 16, 50 ) t3 USING (part_id)
SET t1.approval_status = 1 
WHERE t2.cum_sum <= t3.qty
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=0aad358941f66d1f385799072237d513

Source data must be formed as a query text - see subquery `t3`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to pass multiple part_id's with quantity in the same query? Example: Instead of @part_id, (16,17) with quantities for both part_ids

Comment: parse this multi-data to a rowset with one part_id per row, and use it in the rowsourse of the query instead of UDVs -- Can you plz paste the format. I will generate the rowset as per that.

Comment: Can you update this in the answer query. I'm not sure how to pass the above format to the mysql query.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(@json,
                               '$[*]' COLUMNS ( part_id INT PATH '$....' at line 6  -  Getting this error when I run the code in the DB.

Comment: Evan I tried directly like this, but same error - JOIN JSON_TABLE('[{"part_id":17,"qty":90},{"part_id":16,"qty":50}]',
                               '$[*]'

Comment: @Hello My code is not applicable to MariaDB - it is MySQL-specific (and, maybe, will work in OracleDB).

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '('[{"part_id":17,"qty":90},{"part_id":16,"qty":50}]',
          ...' at line 6

Comment: @Hello What is **precise** server version?

Comment: Local - 10.4.14-MariaDB

Comment: In my live DB, it's showing as 5.6.41-84.1

Comment: @Hello 10.4.14-MariaDB Must accept 1st variant. 5.6.41 - too old version, think about upgrading to actual version.

Comment: Is it a good idea to use the solution 1( Single data ) in a php foreach? So the update query will iterate for all the rows. Performance wise?

Comment: @Hello Solution for MySQL 5.6 added.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. part_id and qty will change dynamically. In third query part_id, qty looks hard coded. Is it ok if I use the single data (query 1) in a php foreach - performance wise, etc?

Comment: *In third query part_id, qty looks hard coded.* Form/create this whole subquery text from your data and insert into the query. *Is it ok if I use the single data (query 1) in a php foreach - performance wise, etc?* You're the only who can test this and decide.